# Scene2D set table cell size in percentage of tables ´s size

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

Is it somehow possible to set Scene2D table cell´s size in percentage of the table?

I would like to have orientation independent menu, with buttons filling let´s say 75% percent of the screen, and also to respond on window resizing (desktop version). I have tried several methods, for example using `Value`

```
table.add(button).width(Value.percentWidth(.75F));
```

but when `value.get(actor)` is called inside cell, it is supplied with inner button actor not its container (table).

I have also tried to set it in fixed fashion

```
table.add(button).width(Value.percentWidth(.75F).get(table));
```

This works fine, but since I set pixel value insted of Value object it is not recalculated upon resizing.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You can change the `Actor` that the `Value` acts on by supplying the actor (in your case your `table`) in the constructor like so:

```
table.add(button).width(Value.percentWidth(.75F, table));
```

This will make `Value` use that actor for the `Value#get(actor)` method instead of the default parent actor.